# Remove listener in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

In React app I have `onClick` listener on Header (`handleToggle`). Header has 4 elements, the last element is Edit with own `onClick` listener (edit).
How can I remove from Edit element, the listener that is applied on Header  (`handleToggle`) and keep only his own listener (edit)?

```
<div className="heading-panel" onClick={e => this.handleToggle(e)}>
  <h5>Name</h5>
  <h5>lastName</h5>
  <h5>Number</h5>
  <a onClick={() => this.edit()}>Edit</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You tell the Edit click handler to stop event propagation.

```
<a onClick={e => { e.stopPropagation(); return this.edit();}>Edit</a>
```

That does it in the anonymous handler, but you could pass the event object to `this.edit` and have it do it instead:

```
<a onClick={e => this.edit(e)}>Edit</a>
```

then

```
edit(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // ...
}
```

Live Example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  edit(e) {
    if (this.props.stop) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
    console.log("edit");
  }
  handleToggle() {
    console.log("handleToggle");
  }
  render() {
    return <div className="heading-panel" onClick={e => this.handleToggle(e)}>
      <h5>Name</h5>
      <h5>lastName</h5>
      <h5>Number</h5>
      <a onClick={e => this.edit(e)}>Edit</a>
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <div>Doesn't Stop:</div>
    <Example stop={false} />
    <div>Stops:</div>
    <Example stop={true} />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you T.J., your comment was very helpful.